# How to get User- email Id from hangout messages that are being sent to Rasa server after Rasa<->Google chat integration

Tags: chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core, google-chat

I have integrated Rasa and google chat and able to receive a response in google chat. I am trying to get the user email id of every request I received from google chat. I am not sure how to get the user object from the response as mentioned in google chat API. It will be helpful if you can help me out.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the hangouts channel has a method called `_extract_sender`, see https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/blob/master/rasa/core/channels/hangouts.py#L209

If that isn't fetching the ID that you need, you can maybe add a similar method to the channnel that extracts the email ID from the request JSON

Comment: I was able to get email id by writing new method like this   
    @staticmethod
    def _extract_sender_email(req: Request) -> Text:
        return req.json["user"]["email"]